# how to read this json array in jquery / javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, json

hey i want to read this array

```
{  
   "1":{  
      "name":"41.52862795108241,-5.397956371307373",
      "location":"41.52862795108241,-5.397956371307373",
      "banner":"http:\/\/wpwebsiteinaweekend.com\/wp-content\/plugins\/lifterlms\/assets\/images\/placeholder.png",
      "phone":"23232323232",
      "address":"karachi test karachi 7890"
   },
   "2":{  
      "name":"41.52862795108241,-5.397956371307373",
      "location":"41.52862795108241,-5.397956371307373",
      "banner":"http:\/\/wpwebsiteinaweekend.com\/wp-content\/plugins\/lifterlms\/assets\/images\/placeholder.png",
      "phone":"23232323232",
      "address":"karachi test karachi 7890"
   }
}
```

PS : I am new to programming so am having a hard time reading it

i am using this code but it does not work

```
$.each( obj, function( key, value ) {
  alert( key + ": " + value );
});
```

Comment: Use `value.name` `value.location` etc

Comment: Did my anwser solve problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do the key.name, and so on. Cause those are child elements.

```
 $.each( obj, function( key, value ) {
      console.log( key.name + ": " + value.name);
    console.log( key.location+ ": " + value.location);
    console.log( key.banner+ ": " + value.banner);
    console.log( key.phone+ ": " + value.phone);
    console.log( key.address+ ": " + value.address);
    });
```

### Reason

As you can see down below , The name,location,banner and all those keys are child elements to "1", and so on. So you actually have to point to that by either using the dot notation like i did above or bracket notation. Hope this helped!

```
{  
   "1":{  
      "name":"41.52862795108241,-5.397956371307373",
      "location":"41.52862795108241,-5.397956371307373",
      "banner":"http:\/\/wpwebsiteinaweekend.com\/wp-content\/plugins\/lifterlms\/assets\/images\/placeholder.png",
      "phone":"23232323232",
      "address":"karachi test karachi 7890"
   },
   "2":{  
      "name":"41.52862795108241,-5.397956371307373",
      "location":"41.52862795108241,-5.397956371307373",
      "banner":"http:\/\/wpwebsiteinaweekend.com\/wp-content\/plugins\/lifterlms\/assets\/images\/placeholder.png",
      "phone":"23232323232",
      "address":"karachi test karachi 7890"
   }
}
```

As you can see here. It works:

http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=streamer&s=btoIFQx0RZvhqbpK

Here is the image of the result of above plunker:
[image]

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length'

Comment: http://web51.startupbug.net/map-search-page/ there will be a map then selet a category from the drop down then check the console you will see the error

Comment: @muhammadzeeshan im not worried about that page. Im trying to solve the problem you asked in this question. And as you can see in the plunker i provided below on my anwser, the question is solved. No error shows

Comment: Now i gave you a image to look at @muhammadzeeshan

Comment: it worked this error was just because i had to add JSON.parse(data)